# How to get all contacts in Android and ignore email-only contacts

Tags: java, android

Below is the code I am using to fetch contacts in Android.

```
String[] projectionFields = new String[]{
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        };

CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(context,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                projectionFields, // the columns to retrieve
                SELECTION, // the selection criteria (none)
                null, // the selection args (none)
                null // the sort order (default)
        );
Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

            do {
                String contactDisplayName = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
```

**I am also getting a lot of email only contacts. I don't want to show email-only contacts. How can I go about this?**

Comment: Do you want to keep contacts having phone number only?

Answer (score 1):

I understand from your question that you need to get the contacts that has phone numbers. If this is the case, you can check if the contact has phone number by

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    ContentProviderClient mCProviderClient = contentResolver.acquireContentProviderClient(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
    Cursor cursor = mCProviderClient.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String contactId =
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                Cursor phones = mCProviderClient.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION_PHONE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
                while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                    String number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                }
                phones.close();
             }
        }
        mCProviderClient.close();
        cursor.close();
    }
```

The value of hasPhoneNumber will be > 0, if there is a phone number assigned to the contact.

Comment: Thanks I will try it out. I have a follow up question too. 

While fetching contacts I see multiple ids for same, person. For eg. One of my contacts who has only 1 phone number. But while logging in the above code it shows multiple contacts. Any idea, how can I group such multiple entries.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a working copy that I have used, please check with it.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46645368/7329667) answer, it will allow only numbers and will also remove duplication.

Hope you find it helpful and your problem gets resolved.

Thanks.